# How to properly make a dynamically allocated multi-array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have been working to create a set of functions that allow for the creation and manipulation of a dynamically allocated array in C for any data type.  I have created several functions, but of most relevance to this post are the following functions;

**vector_mem_alloc** This function is not called directly, but when indirectly called in a wrapper it allocates memory for the array based on the data type

**init_vector** This function is called directly by a user and is a wrapper around `vector_mem_alloc`.  This function preps data and instantiates certain parameters in the `Vector` `struct`.

**append_vector** This function allows a user to append the 1-D array with scalar values or another already created array.

The code for these working functions is shown below.

vector.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef enum
{
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE,
    CHAR,
    INT
} dat_type;

typedef struct
{
    void *array;  // Pointer to array
    size_t len;   // Active length of array
    size_t size;  // Number of allocated indizes
    int elem;     // Memory consumption per indice
    char name[20];   // The array name
    dat_type dat;
} Vector;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void vector_mem_alloc(Vector *array, size_t num_indices);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Vector init_vector(dat_type dat, size_t num_indices, char *name);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int append_vector(Vector *array, void *elements, size_t count);

#endif /* ARRAY_H */
```

vector.c

```
#include "vector.h"

// Begin code
void vector_mem_alloc(Vector *array, size_t num_indices) {
    // Determine the total memory allocation and assign to pointer
    void *pointer;
    pointer = malloc(num_indices * array->elem);

    // If memory is full fail gracefully
    if (pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        free(pointer);
        exit(0);
    }
    // Allocate resources and instantiate Array
    else {
        array->array = pointer;
        array->len = 0;
        array->size = num_indices;
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Vector init_vector(dat_type dat, size_t num_indices, char *name) {
    // Determine memory blocks based on data type
    int size;
    switch(dat) {
        case FLOAT:
            size = sizeof(float);
            break;
        case INT:
            size = sizeof(int);
            break;
        case DOUBLE:
            size = sizeof(double);
            break;
        case CHAR:
            size = sizeof(char);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Data type not correctly entered, instantiating int array!\n");
            size = sizeof(int);
            dat = INT;
    }

    // Allocate indice size and call array_mem_alloc
    Vector array;
    array.dat = dat;
    array.elem = size;
    vector_mem_alloc(&array, num_indices);
    strncpy(array.name, name, sizeof(array.name));
    return array;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int append_vector(Vector *array, void *elements, size_t count) {
    // Allocae more memory if necessary
    if (array->len + count > array->size) {
        size_t size = (array->len + count) * 2;
        void *pointer = realloc(array->array, size * array->elem);
        // If memory is full return operations
        if (pointer == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        // Allocate memory to variables and increment array size
        array->array = pointer;
        array->size = size;
    }
    // Append variables and increment the array length
    memcpy((char *)array->array + array->len * array->elem, elements, count * array->elem);
    array->len += count;
    return 1;
}
```

main.c

```
// - This shows an implementation for an integer array, but it works
//   for FLOAT, DOUBLE, and CHAR as well.
size_t indices = 10;
char name[6] = "array";
dat_type dtype = INT;
Vector arr_test = init_vector(dtype, indices, name);
int a[3] = {10, 9, 8};
append_vector(&arr_test, &a, 3);
```

Everything listed above works just fine.  However, I am trying to expand the capability of the above code to cover multi-arrays of any data type; however, in the near term I am particularly interested in string arrays.  I am trying to add another `struct` to the `vector.h` file that references `marray[]` as a data type of `Vector`.  In the long run, I hope to be able to reference the `name` of each array in the multi-array and treat it similar to a dictionary.  I have tried several function that might allow an interface like shown below, but so far none of them work.  Does anyone have any suggestions that I might be able to use as a starting point in building this functionality.  My intended addition to the `vector.h` file is shown below with a `main.c` implentation that shows how I hope to interface with this.

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t len;
    size_t size;
    int elem;
    dat_type dat;
    Vector *marray[];
} MVector;

size_t indices = 10;
dat_type dtype = INT;
MVector arr_test = init_vector(dtype, indices);
int a[3] = {10, 9, 8};
append_vector(&arr_test[0], &a, 3);
int b = 3;
append_vector(&arr_test[1], &b, 1);
append_vector(&arr_test[1], &b, 1);
b = 4;
append_vector(&arr_test[1], &b, 1)
append_vector(&arr_test[1], &b, 1);
// result [[10, 9, 8], [3, 3, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'multi-array'?  If you mean a 2D array, or a 3D array, or an N-dimensional array, you have your work cut out.  Will a 1D array (vector) of `char` hold a single string or an array or strings?  Both are valid choices — but the implementations are different, of course.

Comment: For the most simple implementation I am trying to develop an array of strings, where I do not need to set the size of the array or the strings at compile time, and the length of each string may not be the same.

Comment: There are a couple of ways of handling strings — one where the array code makes a copy of the strings passed to it (so it doesn't matter what happens to the original strings after they're stored in the array), and one where the array code simply stores the pointer to the original string and the onus is on the programmer to make sure the strings don't change or go out of scope after the pointer is stored in the array.

Comment: My code for this can be found in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `aomcopy.c`, `aomcopy.h`, `aomptr.c`, `aomptr.h`, `aoscopy.c`, `aoscopy.h`, `aosptr.c` and `aosptr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  The 'aos' prefix/acronym is for 'array of strings'.  The 'aom' prefix/acronum is for 'array of memory'.  They may help you, or they may simply intimidate you (and if so, I'm sorry).

Comment: Jon, Curious, why `int size` and not some `unsigned_type size`?  Using a signed type here increases mixed sign-ness operations.

Comment: "for any data type" is hard to archive with an enumerated list of 4 types.  Passing in the size of the type rather than a `dat_type` is a first step.

Comment: This question was probably too broad.  I just posted a more focused question at the following address.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71993262/how-do-i-allocate-memory-for-a-new-string-in-a-c-multiarray