# How do I allocate memory for a new string in a C Multiarray?

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings

I am trying to find a way to create a dynamically allocated array of C strings.  So far I have come with the following code that allows me to initialize an array of strings and change the value of an already existing index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void replace_index(char *array[], int index, char *value) {
    array[index] = malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
    memmove(array[index], value, strlen(value) + 1);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *strs[] = {"help", "me", "learn", "dynamic", "strings"};
    replace_index(strs, 2, "new_value");

    // The above code works fine, but I can not use it to add a value
    // beyond index 4.

    // The following line will not add the string to index 5.
    replace_index(strs, 5, "second_value");
}
```

The function `replace_index` will work to change the value of a string already include in the initializer, but will not work to add strings beyond the maximum index in the initializer.  Is there a way to allocate more memory and add a new index?

Comment: "is there a way to allocate more memory  and add a new index?" --> No. Code never allocated memory for the _array_ `strs`, so can not add _more_ to an array.

Comment: The high-level question is, "is there a way to create a dynamically allocated array of strings"  I know it can be done with a 1-D array, is there no way to do it with Multi-arrays?

Comment: If you want to dynamically change the length of `strs`, then change it to a pointer (type `char **`), and allocate it with `malloc`.  Then your function can call `realloc` to change its size (and return the new pointer to the caller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you want to do serious string manipulation it would be so much easier to use almost any other language or to get a library to do it for you.

Anyway, onto the answer.

The reason `replace_index(strs, 5, "second_value");` doesn't work in your code is because 5 is out of bounds-- the function would write to memory unassociated with `strs`. That wasn't your question, but that's something important to know if you didn't. Instead, it looks like you want to append a string. The following code should do the trick.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char **content;
    int len;
} string_array;

void free_string_array(string_array *s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s->len; i++) {
        free(s->content[i]);
    }
    free(s->content);
    free(s);
}

int append_string(string_array *s, char *value) {
    value = strdup(value);
    if (!value) {
        return -1;
    }
    s->len++;
    char **resized = realloc(s->content, sizeof(char *)*s->len);
    if (!resized) {
        s->len--;
        free(value);
        return -1;
    }
    resized[s->len-1] = value;
    s->content = resized;
    return 0;
}

string_array* new_string_array(char *init[]) {
    string_array *s = calloc(1, sizeof(string_array));
    if (!s || !init) {
        return s;
    }
    while (*init) {
        if (append_string(s, *init)) {
            free_string_array(s);
            return NULL;
        }
        init++;
    }
    return s;
}

// Note: It's up to the caller to free what was in s->content[index]
int replace_index(string_array *s, int index, char *value) {
    value = strdup(value);
    if (!value) {
        return -1;
    }
    s->content[index] = value;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    string_array *s = new_string_array((char *[]) {"help", "me", "learn", "dynamic", "strings", NULL});
    if (!s) {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    free(s->content[2]);
    // Note: No error checking for the following two calls
    replace_index(s, 2, "new_value");
    append_string(s, "second value");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s->len; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", s->content[i]);
    }
    free_string_array(s);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you don't *have* to keep the `char **` and `int` in a struct together but it's much nicer if you do.

If you don't want to use this code, the key takeaway is that the array of strings (`char **` if you prefer) must be dynamically allocated. Meaning, you would need to use `malloc()` or similar to get the memory you need, and you would use `realloc()` to get more (or less). Don't forget to `free()` what you get when you're done using it.

My example uses `strdup()` to make copies of `char *`s so that you can always change them if you wish. If you have no intention of doing so it might be easier to remove the `strdup()`ing parts and also the `free()`ing of them.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that other languages have much better structure for handling strings, but I am purposefully trying to use this and other examples to help me master C.  IT will take me a day to digest your response, but this seems identical to how I handle this problem for a 1-D array with exception of the ** notation versus *.

Comment: @Jon an array of `int -> (int) *`; an array of `char * -> (char *) *`.

Comment: @Neil I am not sure I understand your comment shown above ``int -> (int) *`` and ``char -> (char *) *``.  Are you implying that I can use the same method for multi-arrays of integers as long as I correctly cast the types?

Comment: I'm saying you are absolutely correct; a dynamic array of strings, `{ char **conent; int len; }` and a dynamic array of int `{ int *content, int len; }`, share many of the same properties; in C++, you would consider making this a template, (_ie_ `vector`.) Casting essentially turns of the type system, and may be used in the same way, eg, `qsort`, but is fundamentally different.

Answer (score 2):

### Static array

```
char *strs[] = {"help", "me", "learn", "dynamic", "strings"};
```

This declares `strs` as an [array of pointer to char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+*strs%5B%5D) and initializes it with 5 elements, thus the implied `[]` is `[5]`. A more restrictive `const char *strs[]` would be more appropriate if one were not intending to modify the strings.

### Maximum length

```
char strs[][32] = {"help", "me", "learn", "dynamic", "strings"};
```

This declares `strs` as an [array of array 32 of char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+strs%5B%5D%5B32%5D) which is initialized with 5 elements. The 5 elements are zero-filled beyond the strings. One can modify this up to 32 characters, but not add more.

### Maximum capacity singleton for constant strings

```
static struct str_array { size_t size; const char *data[1024]; } strs;
```

This will pre-allocate the maximum capacity at startup and use that to satisfy requests. In this, the *capacity* is 1024, but the `size` can be any number up to the capacity. The reason I've made this `static` is this is typically a lot to put the stack. There is no reason why it couldn't be dynamic memory, as required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

static struct { size_t size; const char *data[1024]; } strs;
static const size_t strs_capacity = sizeof strs.data / sizeof *strs.data;

/** Will reserve `n` pointers to strings. A null return indicates that the size
 is overflowed, and sets `errno`, otherwise it returns the first string. */
static const char **str_array_append(const size_t n) {
    const char **r;
    if(n > strs_capacity - strs.size) { errno = ERANGE; return 0; }
    r = strs.data + strs.size;
    strs.size += n;
    return r;
}

/** Will reserve one pointer to a string, null indicates the string buffer is
 overflowed. */
static const char **str_array_new(void) { return str_array_append(1); }

int main(void) {
    const char **s;
    size_t i;
    int success = EXIT_FAILURE;

    if(!(s = str_array_append(5))) goto catch;
    s[0] = "help";
    s[1] = "me";
    s[2] = "learn";
    s[3] = "dynamic";
    s[4] = "strings";
    strs.data[2] = "new_value";
    if(!(s = str_array_new())) goto catch;
    s[0] = "second_value";

    for(i = 0; i < strs.size; i++) printf("->%s\n", strs.data[i]);
    { success = EXIT_SUCCESS; goto finally; }
catch:
    perror("strings");
finally:
    return success;
}
```

### Dynamic array

```
struct str_array { const char **data; size_t size, capacity; };
```

I think you are asking for a dynamic array of `const char *`. Language-level support of dynamic arrays is not in the standard `C` run-time; one must write one's own. Which is entirely possible, but more involved. Because the size is variable, it will probably be slower, but in the limit as the problem grows, by a constant average.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

/** A dynamic array of constant strings. */
struct str_array { const char **data; size_t size, capacity; };

/** Returns success allocating `min` elements of `a`. This is a dynamic array,
 with the capacity going up exponentially, suitable for amortized analysis. On
 resizing, any pointers in `a` may become stale. */
static int str_array_reserve(struct str_array *const a, const size_t min) {
    size_t c0;
    const char **data;
    const size_t max_size = ~(size_t)0 / sizeof *a->data;
    if(a->data) {
        if(min <= a->capacity) return 1;
        c0 = a->capacity < 5 ? 5 : a->capacity;
    } else {
        if(!min) return 1;
        c0 = 5;
    }
    if(min > max_size) return errno = ERANGE, 0;
    /* `c_n = a1.625^n`, approximation golden ratio `\phi ~ 1.618`. */
    while(c0 < min) {
        size_t c1 = c0 + (c0 >> 1) + (c0 >> 3);
        if(c0 >= c1) { c0 = max_size; break; } /* Unlikely. */
        c0 = c1;
    }
    if(!(data = realloc(a->data, sizeof *a->data * c0)))
        { if(!errno) errno = ERANGE; return 0; }
    a->data = data, a->capacity = c0;
    return 1;
}

/** Returns a pointer to the `n` buffered strings in `a`, that is,
 `a + [a.size, a.size + n)`, or null on error, (`errno` will be set.) */
static const char **str_array_buffer(struct str_array *const a,
    const size_t n) {
    if(a->size > ~(size_t)0 - n) { errno = ERANGE; return 0; }
    return str_array_reserve(a, a->size + n)
        && a->data ? a->data + a->size : 0;
}

/** Makes any buffered strings in `a` and beyond if `n` is greater then the
 buffer, (containing uninitialized values) part of the size. A null on error
 will only be possible if the buffer is exhausted. */
static const char **str_array_append(struct str_array *const a,
    const size_t n) {
    const char **b;
    if(!(b = str_array_buffer(a, n))) return 0;
    return a->size += n, b;
}

/** Returns a pointer to a string that has been buffered and created from `a`,
 or null on error. */
static const char **str_array_new(struct str_array *const a) {
    return str_array_append(a, 1);
}

/** Returns a string array that has been zeroed, with zero strings and idle,
 not taking up any dynamic memory. */
static struct str_array str_array(void) {
    struct str_array a;
    a.data = 0, a.capacity = a.size = 0;
    return a;
}

/** Erases `a`, if not null, and returns it to idle, not taking up dynamic
 memory. */
static void str_array_(struct str_array *const a) {
    if(a) free(a->data), *a = str_array();
}

int main(void) {
    struct str_array strs = str_array();
    const char **s;
    size_t i;
    int success = EXIT_FAILURE;

    if(!(s = str_array_append(&strs, 5))) goto catch;
    s[0] = "help";
    s[1] = "me";
    s[2] = "learn";
    s[3] = "dynamic";
    s[4] = "strings";
    strs.data[2] = "new_value";
    if(!(s = str_array_new(&strs))) goto catch;
    s[0] = "second_value";
    for(i = 0; i < strs.size; i++) printf("->%s\n", strs.data[i]);
    { success = EXIT_SUCCESS; goto finally; }
catch:
    perror("strings");
finally:
    str_array_(&strs);
    return success;
}
```

Comment: It was a good answer until the wall of strangely and inconsistently formatted code. You really ought to adopt a conventional coding style with consistent indention, consistent brace placement and empty lines at suitable places.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for noticing that; it was taken from a macro definition.

Answer (score 1):

> but will not work to add strings beyond the maximum index in the initializer

To do that, you need the pointer array to be dynamic as well. To create a dynamic array of strings is one of the very few places where using a pointer-to-pointer to emulate 2D arrays is justified:

```
size_t n = 5;
char** str_array = malloc(5 * sizeof *str_array);
...
size_t size = strlen(some_string)+1;
str_array[i] = malloc(size);
memcpy(str_array[i], some_string, size);
```

You have to keep track of the used size `n` manually and `realloc` more room in `str_array` when you run out of it. `realloc` guarantees that previous values are preserved.

This is very flexible but that comes at the cost of fragmented allocation, which is relatively slow. Had you used fixed-size 2D arrays, the code would perform much faster but then you can't resize them.

Note that I used `memcpy`, not `memmove` - the former is what you should normally use, since it's the fastest. `memmove` is for specialized scenarios where you suspect that the two arrays being copied may overlap.

As a side-note, the `strlen` + `malloc` + `memcpy` can be replaced with `strdup`, which is currently a non-standard function (but widely supported). It seems likely that `strdup` will become standard in the upcoming C23 version of C, so using it will become recommended practice.